# why webpack is looking for .json module when it is actually a ES6 JSON file read

Tags: json, ecmascript-6, webpack

Node app.js in ES6 has a JSON being read from file per request (not ideal but there is a situation)

```
JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`../../src/components/${componentName}/mock.props.json`).toString());
```

tried

```
new webpack.IgnorePlugin(new RegExp("\.json"))
```

which ignored all .json from request or webpack's fileDependencies:

but still get the error in client bundle.js 's webpack-entry.js

```
bootstrap df7a535…:39Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "../../src/components/xxx.json"webpackMissingModule @ bootstrap df7a535…:39(anonymous function) @ bootstrap
```

When the filename is changed from mock.props.json to mock.content.json, this error goes away. webpack starts seeing this as content and not module? Don't want this to be looked up as module, its just a file read.

node version 4.3.2

webpack 1.13

Answer (score 0):

By using `fs.readFile` webpack doesn't think of this as a dependency (as it isn't).

Require it instead:

```
require(`../../src/components/${componentName}/mock.props.json`);
```

Comment: webpack is thinking this as a dependency, and that is the problem.